# How to write a generic adapter/-interface class for accessing 3rd party objects?

Tags: javascript, interface, adapter, es6-class, prototype-programming

I would like to have a generic `class` that accepts an object, which is not *under my control* (e.g. 3rd party lib), and provides an interface for accessing custom properties defined by callbacks.

The adapter should behave like `object{}` :

- The values should not be static/or cached,
- Getter for access: `adapter.id` returns `{number}`
- Iterate an adapter

  - `for...of` loop -> loop over `keys` from `config`
  - `for...in` loop -> loop over `values` (run callbacks from `config`)
- `JSON.stringify(adapter)`
- `Object.entries(adapter)` [nice 2 have]

### Something like this:

[image]

If there is an `obj` like this …

```js
let obj = {
    id: 1,
    getName: () => 'myName',
    type: () => ({get: () => 'myType'})
}
```

… with a `config` like …

```js
let config= {
    id:   self => self.obj.id,
    name: self => self.obj.getName(),
    type: self => self.obj.type().get()
};
```

I can **build** a re-usable `class AdapterBlueprint{}`and access like this:

```
let AdapterBlueprint = Adapter.factory(config);
let myAdapter = new AdapterBlueprint(obj);
console.log('myAdapter.id',   myAdapter.id);   // => 1
console.log('myAdapter.name', myAdapter.name); // => 'myName'
console.log('myAdapter.type', myAdapter.type); // => 'myType'

let myAdapter2 = new AdapterBlueprint(obj2);
…
```

End of question

---

### My try:

I have already an implementation but it looks bulky in my eyes and comes with some pitfalls. So, please do not stick to my implementation I´m open for any solution.
The idea I had:

- An *abstract* `Adapter` class I can `extend` from to get new classes on demand
- Add **enumerable** `get()` properties for each `config[_key_]` to its **prototype**

```js
class AbstractAdapter {
    constructor(obj) {
        AbstractAdapter.defineProperty(this, 'obj', () => obj, false, true); // _private_ non-enumerable access
    }

    /**
     * defines 2 properties: 1. access to callback adapter method + (public) getter that invokes the callback
     * -> property for callback has Symbol() key (non enumerable)
     * @param {Object} target
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {function} value
     * @param {boolean} onProto     - if true properties will be added to target.prototype
     * @param {boolean} isPrivate   - if true property Getter is 'enumerable = false' (hidden when looping props)
     */
    static defineProperty(target, name, value, onProto = true, isPrivate = false) {
        target = onProto && target.prototype ? target.prototype : target;
        let prop = Symbol.for(name);

        Reflect.defineProperty(target, prop,
            Object.assign({}, AbstractAdapter.configPropSymbol, {
                value: value
            })
        );

        Reflect.defineProperty(target, name,
            Object.assign({}, isPrivate ? AbstractAdapter.configPrivateGetter : AbstractAdapter.configPublicGetter, {
                get() {
                    return this[prop](this);
                }
            })
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {Object<string,function>} config
     * @returns {AbstractAdapter}
     */
    static factory(name, config = {}) {
        /**
         * get a new named Class that extends from AbstractAdapter
         * -> we need a new prototype where we can add adapter properties from config at
         * @param {string} name
         * @param {AbstractAdapter} cls
         * @returns {Object}
         */
        let namedClass = (name, cls) => ({
            [name]: class extends cls {
                constructor(...args) {
                    super(...args);
                }
            }
        })[name];
        // get new named Class
        let adapter = namedClass(name, this);

        // add all adapter callbacks + accessors to the prototype
        for (let [key, closure] of Object.entries(config)) {
            adapter.defineProperty(adapter, key, closure, true, false);
        }
        // freeze prototype -> prevents manipulation from now
        Object.freeze(adapter.prototype);
            
        return adapter;
    }

}


AbstractAdapter.configPropSymbol = {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false
};

AbstractAdapter.configPublicGetter = {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true
};

AbstractAdapter.configPrivateGetter = {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false
};
```

And then init like this:

```
let AdapterBlueprint = AbstractAdapter.factory('AdapterBlueprint', config);
let myAdapter = new AdapterBlueprint($obj);
console.log('myAdapter.id',   myAdapter.id);   // => 1
console.log('myAdapter.name', myAdapter.name); // => 'myName'
```

... a lot of code in my eyes. My decision to define the properties in the **prototype** turned out to be not ideal when it comes to loops. Because of prototype get() props are not "visible" in `for...in`. I had to "point" to the prototype keys manually.

```js
/**
 * required for loop over an instance for...of loop
 * -> get keys from prototype (since they are defined there)
 * @returns {Generator<any, void, *>}
 */
* [Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let key in this.constructor.prototype) {
        if(this.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            yield Reflect.get(this, key);
        }
    }
}
```

...same thing for `JSON.stringify()`. I have to implement the native `toJSON()` method and use the prototype keys...

```js
/**
 * reserved toJSON() method
 * -> called by JSON.stringify()
 * -> get keys from prototype (since they are defined there)
 * @returns {{}}
 */
toJSON() {
    return Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype).reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = this[key];
        return obj;
    }, {});
}
```

I think there must be a smarter way to get what I want. It feels like "re-implementing" all the stuff native `{object}` already has.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the javascript [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object. Your `AdapterBlueprint` is analogous to the `handler` argument of the `Proxy` constructor.

> The Proxy object enables you to create a proxy for another object, which can intercept and redefine fundamental operations for that object.

Rather than using an extendable `abstract` class, you should create different instances of a generalized handler by passing the configuration as an argument to the constructor.  Any of those instances can create an object proxy.

I wrote this in typescript, but you could remove the annotations and the JS would still work the same.

We define a configuration as a key-value object where each key is the key that we want to access on the adapted version.  The corresponding value is either a function that maps from the original object to the adapted value or it can be a fixed value.

```
type Config<ObjectType, AdaptedProperties> = {
    [K in keyof AdaptedProperties]: ((self: ObjectType) => AdaptedProperties[K]) | AdaptedProperties[K];
}
```

We use that config as the sole constructor argument for our `AdapterHandler`.  Instances of this class can be used as the `handler` for a `Proxy`.  I've put the `Proxy` instantiation inside of a class method `adaptObject`, which takes an object and creates a proxied version of it from this handler instance.

The class methods `ownKeys`, `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, `has`, `get`, and `set` are all expected properties of a proxy handler which define how the `Proxy` will function.

```
class AdapterHandler<ObjectType extends object, AdaptedProperties extends object> implements ProxyHandler<ObjectType> {

    private readonly config: Config<ObjectType, AdaptedProperties>;

    constructor(config: Config<ObjectType, AdaptedProperties>) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    private isConfigKey = (property: PropertyKey): property is keyof AdaptedProperties => {
        return property in this.config;
    }

    ownKeys(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(config);
    }

    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target: ObjectType, property: PropertyKey): PropertyDescriptor | undefined {
        return (this.isConfigKey(property)) ? ({
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false,
        }) : undefined;
    }

    has(target: ObjectType, property: PropertyKey): boolean {
        return this.isConfigKey(property);
    }

    get(target: ObjectType, property: PropertyKey): any {
        if (this.isConfigKey(property)) {
            const accessor = this.config[property];
            return ( typeof accessor === "function" ) ? accessor(target) : accessor;
        }
    }

    set() {
        return false;
    }

    adaptObject( object: ObjectType ): AdaptedProperties {
        return new Proxy( object, this ) as unknown as AdaptedProperties;
    }
}
```

My config is a little bit different from what you wrote because I couldn't see a use case where a mapper would depend on the handler and not just the object, but you could tweak that.

My usage looks like this:

```
const config: Config<typeof obj, ObjAdapted> = {
    id: obj => obj.id,
    name: obj => obj.getName(),
    type: obj => obj.type().get(),
    overwritten: 0,
};

const myAdapter = new AdapterHandler(config);

const adapterInstance = myAdapter.adaptObject(obj);
```

With this approach, you can call methods from the `Object.prototype` such as `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` directly on your proxied object.

```
console.log(
    adapterInstance.id, // 1
    adapterInstance.name, // "myName"
    adapterInstance.type, // "myType"
    adapterInstance.overwritten, // 0
    Object.keys(adapterInstance), // ["id", "name", "type", "overwritten"]
    Object.entries(adapterInstance) // [["id", 1], ["name", "myName"], ["type", "myType"], ["overwritten", 0]]
)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/kNrYaw).  Click the `.JS` tab on the right side to get the pure JS version without typescript annotations.